# How to fake EntityFramework.Extended FutureQuery?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-extended

I'm looking to setup a fake repository.

```
public class FooRepo {

    public FutureFoo<Foo> GetById(int id) {

        var foo = new Foo();
        return new FutureValue(foo);
    }

    public FutureQuery<Foo> GetByCategory(int categoryId) {

        var foos = new[] { new Foo(), new Foo() new Foo() };

        return  //what goes here?
    }

}
```

The purpose of this is for writing data dependent tests while not depending on any database connectivity. This was really straightforward for the `FutureValue<>` type as it provides a constructor that accepts a direct object. However the constructor for `FutureQuery<>` takes the arguments `IQueryable query, Action loadAction`

Can i just ignore `loadAction`?

Such as: `new FutureQuery<Foo>(foos.AsQueryable(), () => { });`

Or what is the proper way to go about this?

---

Coerced solution:

```
(FutureQuery<Foo>) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FutureQuery<Foo>),
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, 
                   new object[] { foos.AsQueryable(), null }, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [`FutureQueryBase.GetResult()`](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source%2FEntityFramework.Extended%2FFuture%2FFutureQueryBase.cs#L74) :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the result by invoking the <see cref="LoadAction"/> if not already loaded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1"/> that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    protected virtual IEnumerable<T> GetResult()
    {
        if (IsLoaded)
            return _result;

        // no load action, run query directly
        if (LoadAction == null)
        {
            _isLoaded = true;
            _result = _query as IEnumerable<T>;
            return _result;
        }

        // invoke the load action on the datacontext
        // result will be set with a callback to SetResult
        LoadAction.Invoke();
        return _result ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
```

You should pass a `null` for the load action, unless you want to explicitly update `_result` through [`SetResult(ObjectContext, DbDataReader)`](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source%2FEntityFramework.Extended%2FFuture%2FFutureQueryBase.cs#L141).

Comment: Actually, if I understand the source correctly, the `loadAction` delegate is expected to call the `SetResult` method (which will in turn set the `_result` field that will be returned). So an empty action won't give the expected result (that is, returning the `IQueryable`). Setting `loadAction` to null seems safer

Comment: @KooKiz Didn't even notice that part... I just went back and reread the code. Indeed, passing a `null` load action is the correct way of doing it, or else an empty sequence will be returned.

Comment: @KooKiz I think you need subclass `FutureQueryBase`, the `FutureQuery` doesn't have a public .ctor.

Comment: Passing in null worked fine. I never looked at the source of the base class after the digging i did in the repo i figured i was missing something. I originally didn't even notice the constructor was internal because i wasn't sure what i even wanted to pass in to it.